# I need a Select for Max(Version)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two Tables with a foreign key from t1.ID to T2.T_ID

T1:

| ID | PR_ID | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |

T2:

| ID | T_ID | ab_nr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 56 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 76 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 87 |
| 6 | 6 | 64 |

I need a select which gets all T2.IDs with the highest T1.Version. For example T1.PR_ID has the Numbers 2 and 3 with different Versions, here i would only need as end Result the T1.ID 's 1,3,5 and 6.

I tried it with: 
SELECT * FROM T2 
JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T2.T_ID 
WHERE T1.Version IN (SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM T1);
but this doesnt work because it only gets the Number 2 and nothing else.

Comment: SO exists to help with your issues, but it is **not a code writing service**. Please post what you have tried, those results and why they are not correct. You may wish to review [ask\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always a many ways to skin a SQL cat, but here's a simple one.

```
SELECT  t2.* 
FROM    t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t_id = t1.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'higher version for the same PR_ID'
                   FROM   t1 t1x
           WHERE  t1x.pr_id = t1.pr_id
                   AND    t1x.version > t1.version )
```

That is, add a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter out any results that are for old versions.

The way you tried to do it was on the right track, but you just needed to correlate your `MAX(VERSION)` subquery so that it got the max version *for the current `PR_ID`*.  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T2
JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T2.T_ID
WHERE T1.Version IN (SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM T1X 
                     -- You missed this part, below
                     WHERE T1X.PR_ID = T1.PR_ID
                    );
```

Anyway, try either of these.  If performance is not good, we can start looking at more efficient ways of doing it (e.g., `MAX ... KEEP`)

Comment: Ok i got it, yeah its easy and there are no performance issues. just for curiosity, how would you do it with MAX? :)

Comment: Something like `SELECT t2.* FROM   t2 INNER JOIN ( SELECT max(id) keep ( dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY version ) id FROM t1 GROUP BY pr_id ) t1 ON t1.id = t2.t_id` could save an extra read of `T1`.  Hard to tell without access to realistically-sized tables.